# Show that $((∃x)A ∧ B) ⇔ ∃x (A ∧ B)$.

Tags: logic

**Show that $((∃x)A ∧ B) ⇔ ∃x (A ∧ B)$.**

My attempt so far:

Let $I$ be an interpretation with domain $D$ and let $v$ be an $I$-assignment.

Suppose that $I⊨((∃x)A ∧ B)$. We want to show that $I⊨∃x (A ∧ B)$

I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: I wonder if there is a restriction omitted that $x$ does not appear free in $B$.

Comment: Sorry for overlooking that - the original question says, "Let A and B be predicate forms and let x be a variable which does not occur free in A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand all the definitions completely.

What you are given is that $I \vDash \exists x\ ( A )$ and $I \vDash B$, by definition of the semantics of "$\land$". Again, expand by definition what "$I \vDash \exists x\ ( A )$" means, which says that there is some $e \in D$ such that $I[x:=e] \vDash A$. ("$[x:=e]$" means that any free occurrence of $x$ on the right of the "$\vDash$" is to be interpreted as $e$ instead of according to $I$.)

And what you want to show is that there is some $a \in D$ such that $I[x:=a] \vDash (A \land B)$. Again, by definition it would be enough to show that $I[x:=a] \vDash A$ and $I[x:=a] \vDash B$.

Can you see how to finish, and how exactly the assumption that $x$ does not occur free in $B$ is used?